# Route testing with WebApiContrib

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing, web-api-contrib

I have a WebApi project that I am trying to test. I have a controller -

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

I need to test the route and I am trying to use [WebApiContrib.Testing](http://nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Testing) package.

Now, my problem is that while registering routes, I use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes` which is of type `HttpRouteCollection`.

In my test, I can access `RouteTable.Routes` but this is of type `RouteCollection`.

As a result, I can't register the WebApi routes in my test, because of this type incompatibility.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this by using:

```
WebApiConfig.Register( GlobalConfiguration.Configuration );
```

In `TestFixtureSetup`

Comment: This works fine until you have two test fixtures that need to register the configuration ;)  Do you know how to "unregister" or "dispose" of a previous registration?

Comment: You just need to call `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.Clear()` before you call `WebApiConfig.Register( GlobalConfiguration.Configuration )` to avoid the routes getting mapped multiple times.

Comment: This makes the Get based tests work, but I'm not having any joy with POST etc - can anyone offer any insight? Details here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377365/testing-asp-net-web-api-post-and-parameterless-get-routes-with-webapicontrib-tes